# Vectorize calculation of a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a trivial problem that I have solved using loops, but I am trying to see if there is a way I can attempt to vectorize some of it to try and improve performance.

Essentially I have 2 dataframes (DF_A and DF_B), where the rows in DF_B are based on a sumation of a corresponding row in DF_A and the row above in DF_B. I do have the first row of values in DF_B.

```
df_a = [
  [1,2,3,4]
  [5,6,7,8]
  [..... more rows]
]
df_b = [
 [1,2,3,4] 
 [ rows of all 0 values here, so dimensions match df_a]
]
```

What I am trying to achive is that the 2nd row in df_b for example will be the values of the first row in df_b + the values of the second row in df_a. So in this case:

```
df_b.loc[2] = [6,8,10,12]
```

I was able to accomplish this using a loop over range of df_a, keeping the previous rows value saved off and then adding the row of the current index to the previous rows value. Doesn't seem super efficient.

Comment: Can you provide a valid sample data set and your expected output?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `numpy` solution. This should be significantly faster than a `pandas` loop, especially since it uses JIT-compiling via `numba`.

```
from numba import jit

a = df_a.values
b = df_b.values

@jit(nopython=True)
def fill_b(a, b):
    for i in range(1, len(b)):
        b[i] = b[i-1] + a[i]
    return b

df_b = pd.DataFrame(fill_b(a, b))

#     0   1   2   3
# 0   1   2   3   4
# 1   6   8  10  12
# 2  15  18  21  24
# 3  28  32  36  40
# 4  45  50  55  60
```

**Performance benchmarking**

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
from numba import jit

df_a = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,1000001).reshape(1000,1000))

@jit(nopython=True)
def fill_b(a, b):
    for i in range(1, len(b)):
        b[i] = b[i-1] + a[i]
    return b

def jp(df_a):

    a = df_a.values
    b = np.empty(df_a.values.shape)
    b[0] = np.arange(1, 1001)

    return pd.DataFrame(fill_b(a, b))

%timeit df_a.cumsum()  # 16.1 ms
%timeit jp(df_a)       # 6.05 ms
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I tested both and they do work as expected.

Comment: thats interesting, i honestly expected cumsum to be quicker. i'm on python 3.6, pandas 0.20.3. is that what you have? also what did you get for numpy version?

Comment: Same thing, but I get 6.05 ms `numba`, 16.1 ms `pandas` and 13.3 ms `numpy`, its still faster, i just had a hard time believing there was such a huge gap

Answer (score 1):

You can just create `df_b` using the cumulative sum over `df_a`, like so

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,17).reshape(4,4))
df_b = df_a.cumsum()

    0   1   2   3
0   1   2   3   4
1   6   8  10  12
2  15  18  21  24
3  28  32  36  40
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I knew it had to be simple

Comment: @jpp, i do not. Im sure if you post a question someone here will know

Comment: Related: [Pandas vectorised function cumsum versus numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49164134/pandas-vectorised-function-cumsum-versus-numpy)